# Anti-XSS library - Use with ASP .Net website (vs. web application)?

Tags: asp.net, xss, antixsslibrary

The results of a security audit revealed that our site may be vulnerable to XSS attacks.  Currently the only protection we have against this is by using the default ValidateRequest="true" on all pages.  I have been looking into Microsoft's Anti-XSS library and after watching [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Jossie/Anti-XSS-Library-v31-Find-Fix-and-Verify-Errors) I would like to implement the Security Runtime Engine Module to protect all pages rather than manually encoding each individual item **[[1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Jossie/Anti-XSS-Library-v31-Find-Fix-and-Verify-Errors)]**.

The problem I am having is generating the antixssmodule.config file using the SRE configuration generator.  It is looking for an assembly but our site is built using a Website project and not a Web Application project and is therefor not built into an assembly.  Am I still able to generate the config file somehow so that I can use SRE, or perhaps there is a download-able version of this file with the commonly exploited controls already defined?

**[[1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Jossie/Anti-XSS-Library-v31-Find-Fix-and-Verify-Errors)]** I also can't use the CAT.NET tool to discover all possible vulnerabilities because that tool is looking for an assembly also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically no, you can't generate without a target assembly, so website projects won't work. You could, of course, use the default web.config which gets all the Microsoft web controls (I believe).

However, the SRE is meant as a patch around vulnerable web sites until you can get them fixed, it's not a permanent solution. A better approach would be to address the underlying issues and make sure you're encoding all untrusted input before outputting it to the browser.